# Не обновляет контакт в MailChimp

Tags: php

Невозможно обновить теги для созданных контактов в MailChimp. Ребят покажите пожалуйста как добавить уже подписанному контакту теги используя [эту либу](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52298226/4496422

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ [на гитхабе в issue](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/issues/300):

```
$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash/tags", [
    'tags' => array(
         [
            'name' => 'tagname',
            'status' => 'inactive'
         ],
        [
           'name' => 'othertag',
            'status' => 'active'
        ]
     )
]);
```